# How to prove that there are only K distinct rows in eigenvector matrix when the original matrix only has k distinct rows?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Assumes we have a real symmetric matrix $A_{n,n}$ and the corresponding eigen decomposition of it is

$ A = UDU^T$

where $U^TU = I_K$, $D \in R^{K\times K}$ is the diagonal matrix with non-zero eigenvalues.

The question is that if there are only k distinct rows in $A$, how can we prove that there are also only $K$ distinct rows in $U$?

Comment: We can't. What if $A=0$?

Comment: This can’t possibly be true.  It’s easy for $A$ to have $k<n$, for instance the all-ones matrix or the zero matrix.  But $U$ is always invertible, so it can’t possibly have only $k$ distinct rows as that would make its rank $\le k$.

Comment: @ErickWong,@amsmath sorry, I forget to write down the dimension of the $D$. Now, the question is valid

Comment: It seems more plausible but I disagree that this can be called an eigendecomposition. Given that it’s not, I think you should be more clear on what properties it can be assumed to have.  Is it a given that $D$ consists of the regular diagonal matrix with $n-k$ zeroes removed?  Or is that something to be *proven* from the validity of the decomposition?  Is $D$ even diagonal? (surely yes but if it’s not a standard object it should be stated clearly)

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, it is a diagonal matrix with all those zeros removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U^T U = I_k$, the $k\times n$ matrix $U^T$ has full rank, so its $k$ rows are linearly independent $n$-vectors.  Since $D$ has nonzero diagonal it is invertible, so $DU^T$ also consists of $k$ independent rows.

By definition of matrix multiplication, each row of $A = UDU^T$ consists of a linear combination of the rows of $DU^T$, whose coefficients come from the corresponding row of $U$.  Since the former’s rows are independent, a distinct combination will always yield a distinct row.  The converse is of course also true: the same combination will yield the same row.  Thus the number of distinct rows of $A$ exactly matches the number of distinct rows of $U$.